# React.js does not save state data correctly in socket.io on method

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io

React.js is not saving state data correctly in the socket.io on method. It brings the data correctly only when I log it, but when I use it with state, it sets the socekt.id data incorrectly. I can't understand the reason for this, it does the assignment correctly when I use ref, but can someone explain to me why there is an error when I use state, and of course ref is not updated immediately for some reason, I need to make an emit in the socket.

State Code

```
 const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("connect", async () => {
   setSocektId(socket.id);
  });

  return () => {
    socket.off("connect");
  };
}, []);
```

Ref Code

```
 const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("connect", async () => {
    socketID.current = socket.id;
  });

  return () => {
    socket.off("connect");
  };
}, []);
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You call `io` every time the state changes so you make a new connection multiple times. But you run `useEffect` only once

Comment: I don't quite understand how to fix this. I'm sorry, English is not my native language.If you give me an example I will understand much better thank you in advance

Comment: Move `const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");` into `useEffect`